# Youtube embed video, fullscreen on play button clicked

Tags: javascript, video, youtube

I have Youtube embed code using `iframe`

```
<iframe title="YouTube" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/aaabbbcccddd?wmode=transparent&amp;autoplay=0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

I want that if users click the "Play" button, it automatically goes fullscreen.
As opposed to the user should click "Play" and click "Fullscreen" button -- I want to skip that click "Fullscreen" part.

Is this possible?
Do I need to use Youtube's Javascript API?

Does it have something like this:

```
youtube.onPlayButtonClicked(function() {
    youtube.fullscreen();
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at the [youtube iframe api docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)?

Answer (score 5):

It's possible with the youtube API.

```
var player, iframe;
var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

// init player
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '200',
    width: '300',
    videoId: 'dQw4w9WgXcQ',
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
  });
}

// when ready, wait for clicks
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  var player = event.target;
   iframe = $('#player');
  setupListener(); 
}

function setupListener (){
    $('button').addEventListener('click', playFullscreen);
}

function playFullscreen (){
  player.playVideo();//won't work on mobile

  var requestFullScreen = iframe.requestFullScreen ||    iframe.mozRequestFullScreen || iframe.webkitRequestFullScreen;
  if (requestFullScreen) {
    requestFullScreen.bind(iframe)();
  }
}
```

You can have an exemple at this link :
https://codepen.io/bfred-it/pen/GgOvLM